# Will the inside of a vehicle be too hot for PLA?

Tags: pla

I'm thinking about doing a print to go inside a vehicle. I have PLA at hand, ready to go. Is that gonna work, or will the hot temperatures we sometimes get inside cars on sunny summer days cause the PLA to go soft? If so, what other material should I try?

Comment: PETG is probably a better choice for inside of a vehicle ... but it also depends on the piece and how big it is. I built a small piece out of PLA, which, along with some superglue, was used to provide support for two other pieces and did so without issue.

Comment: That depends on where you enjoy the summer, in Greenland the summers are less warm than in the Sahara.